# jQuery is not defined - WordPress footer.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have custom WordPress theme with my code on footer.php:

```
<script async src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    if(jQuery(document).scrollTop() > 500){
        jQuery("a.toTop").addClass("active");
    }else{
        jQuery("a.toTop").removeClass("active");
    }
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("a.toTop").click(function() {
        return jQuery("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 1e3), !1
    });
});

</script>
```

Web console says:

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Any ideas? Thanks1

Comment: try to remove async here <script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: But better if you will enque all scripts via wp_enqueue_scripts function. BTW jQuery should be loaded by default unless you dequeued the script manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "async" from the jQuery call.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need the "async" attribute in your jQuery script tag ? 
If not, try removing it, it solves the issue.

Comment: Thank you too for validation of async attribute ;)